# Calcular valor de entrada no parcelamento - PHP

Tags: php

Com base na função abaixo, como posso considerar e calcular o valor da entrada no parcelamento, de forma que, o restante seja divido em partes iguais para as demais parcelas?

```
function calculo_negociacao($valor_total, $parcelas, $dt_vencimento, $valor_entrada) {  
    $parcelado = [];

    $valor = $valor_total / $parcelas;
    $valor = number_format((float)$valor, 2, '.', '');

    $parcelado = array_fill(0, $parcelas, ['valor' => $valor]);

    $dt_vencimento = explode( '-', $dt_vencimento);
    $dia = $dt_vencimento[0];
    $mes = $dt_vencimento[1];
    $ano = $dt_vencimento[2];

    for($x = 0; $x < $parcelas; $x++){
        $parcelado[$x]['parcela'] = $x + 1; 
        $parcelado[$x]['dt_vencimento'] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+".$x." month",mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano)));
    }       
    return $parcelado;
}

$valor = 150.07;
$valor_entrada= 50.00;
$parcela = 4;
$dt_vencimento = '04-09-2018';
$negociacao = calculo_negociacao($valor, $parcela, $dt_vencimento, $valor_entrada);
var_dump($negociacao);
echo json_encode($negociacao);
```

Comment: Só está faltando subtrair o valor da entrada do valor total antes de calcular as parcelas. Incluí seu o código aqui.. https://ideone.com/eog1Sa

Comment: @AndreMesquita, obrigado, mas o valor de entrada pode ser ou não informado, caso não seja, será dividido em partes iguais.

Comment: Como assim? Em que momento é para subtrair o valor_entrada do valor_total? É para ser dividido também por cada parcela?

Comment: @Leite, caso o valor da entrada seja maior que 0, então devo considerar o valor da entrada, como a primeira parcela, o o restante divide igualmente para as demais parcelas. um plano de parcelamento com entrada, exemplo 1(entrada) + 3 (parcelas), caso o valor da entrada seja 0, então divide em 4 parcelas iguais. Estou citando 4 parcelas, porque está no exemplo, porem, é uma variável

Comment: @Leite, eu até consegui desta forma, https://ideone.com/QBpdkE, mas acredito que existe uma forma mais simples de ser feito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes por apenas 2 verificações se existe `$valor_entrada` em pontos específicos da função para alterar o seu comportamento, sem teres de separar em 2 blocos distintos que fazem algo muito similar. Ve o código abaixo

```
<?php

function calculo_negociacao($valor_total, $parcelas, $dt_vencimento, $valor_entrada) {  
    $parcelado = [];
    $inicio = 0;

    if ($valor_entrada > 0) {
        $inicio = 1;
        $valor_total = $valor_total - $valor_entrada;
    }

    $valor = $valor_total / ($parcelas - $inicio); // reduzimos 1 parcela se houver entrada ou 0 se nao
    $valor = number_format((float)$valor, 2, '.', '');

    $parcelado = array_fill($inicio, $parcelas - $inicio, ['valor' => $valor]); // $parcelas - 1 pois será menos 1 com a entrada ou 0 se nao houver

    // só depois de calcularmos todos é que podemos adicionar a entrada no inicio
    if ($valor_entrada > 0) {
        array_unshift($parcelado, ['valor' => number_format((float)$valor_entrada, 2, '.', '')]);
    }

    $dt_vencimento = explode( '-', $dt_vencimento);
    $dia = $dt_vencimento[0];
    $mes = $dt_vencimento[1];
    $ano = $dt_vencimento[2];

    for($x = 0; $x < $parcelas; $x++){
        $parcelado[$x]['parcela'] = $x + 1; 
        $parcelado[$x]['dt_vencimento'] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+".$x." month",mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano)));
    }

    return $parcelado;
}

$valor = 150.07;
$valor_entrada= 50.00;
$parcela = 4;
$dt_vencimento = '04-09-2018';
$negociacao = calculo_negociacao($valor, $parcela, $dt_vencimento, $valor_entrada);
//var_dump($negociacao);

echo '<pre>';
echo var_dump($negociacao);
```

Comment: Funcionou muito bem, muito obrigado!

Comment: Olá @Leite, quando puder, pode me ajudar com esta questão https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/408530/calcular-juros-com-parcela-php ?